# how to make one index in multindex be columns in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I tried to make below code useable in dask.

```
daily_register_users = df.groupby(['gid','timestamp')['uid'].apply(set).apply(list)
daily_register_users = daily_register_users.unstack().T
```

I had tried `unstack()`, but it haven't implement in dask, and `dask.pivot_table()` only supports mean ,sum and count.
thanks for any help
my input is
[input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYMUE.png)

expected output is 
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCJtn.png)

Comment: and where i misunderstand the insert code format?when i edit code part  4 backspace before the everyline head,it report me gramma error

Comment: You can try ctrl+k after you selected block of text. About your problem can you give us a sample of your dataframe and what you expect in output?

Comment: @BarthelemyPavy   i add two picture

Comment: @UN2758 post pictures instead of code is not the way SO is supposed to work. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)